# How to use paths in vitest with Nuxt3?

Tags: testing, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vitest

I have `nuxt3_rc_3` project and using `vitest` to test the utilities I wrote for project

`utils/index.ts` imports few constants from `~~/config/constants`

While writing test in `test/utils/index.test.ts` I imported one function to write test when I run test I get this error

```sh
FAIL  test/utils/index.test.ts [ test/utils/index.test.ts ]
Error: [vite-node] Failed to load ~~/config/constants
```

I guess the problem is vitest not reading `./.nuxt/tsconfig.json` for relative path lookup or may be something else wrong please help.

nuxt3's tsconfig for path

```
...
"paths": {
      "~~": [
        "."
      ],
      "~~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@@": [
        "."
      ],
      "@@/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "~": [
        "."
      ],
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@": [
        "."
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "public": [
        "public"
      ],
      "public/*": [
        "public/*"
      ],
      "#app": [
        "node_modules/nuxt/dist/app"
      ],
      "#app/*": [
        "node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/*"
      ],
      "vue-demi": [
        "node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/compat/vue-demi"
      ],
      "pinia": [
        "pinia/dist/pinia"
      ],
      "@intlify/shared": [
        "node_modules/@intlify/shared/dist/shared.esm-bundler"
      ],
      "@intlify/core-base": [
        "node_modules/@intlify/core-base/dist/core-base.esm-bundler"
      ],
      "@intlify/devtools-if": [
        "node_modules/@intlify/devtools-if/dist/devtools-if.esm-bundler"
      ],
      "vue-i18n": [
        "node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.esm-bundler"
      ],
      "#head": [
        "node_modules/nuxt/dist/head/runtime"
      ],
      "#head/*": [
        "node_modules/nuxt/dist/head/runtime/*"
      ],
      "#components": [
        ".nuxt/components"
      ],
      "#imports": [
        ".nuxt/imports"
      ],
      "#build": [
        ".nuxt"
      ],
      "#build/*": [
        ".nuxt/*"
      ]
    }
...
```

Comment: You do have 2 tildes `~~` or only one `~`?

Comment: @kissu I've updated question with nuxt's path configuration. It can be anything throughout the app. Initially for me I'm using `~~` only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using nuxt's ts config's paths as alias in vitest config solves the issue

```
// file alias.ts

import { resolve } from 'path'

const r = (p: string) => resolve(__dirname, p)

export const alias: Record<string, string> = {
  '~~': r('.'),
  '~~/': r('./'),
  '@@': r('.'),
  '@@/': r('./'),

  ... other paths
}
```

```
// vitest.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { alias } from './alias'

export default defineConfig({
  root: '.',
  esbuild: {
    tsconfigRaw: '{}',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias,
  },
})
```

Comment: For those looking for a solution which works with `vitest.config.ts`:
Use the following:
`import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";
import { alias } from "./alias";

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias,
  }, 
`

Comment: I found the same solution and any better

Answer (score 0):

I have some issue. I dont have any idea about the issue.
Currently I have open a discussion for team of nuxt; maybe they can help us.

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/discussions/10480